# How to rearrange the singular value decomposition (SVD)?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, svd

We may carry out the SVD ($A=U\Sigma V^T$) in such a way that the diagonal entries of $\Sigma$ are in descending order.

My question is, how to do this rearrangement? Can someone show me the details?

Another question: is the $A=U'\Sigma' V'^T$ still a valid SVD?

Comment: What do you mean how to do this? You get the singular values of $A$ - get the eigenvalues of $A^{t}A$, take the squre roots of the absoulute values of these eigenvalues, and put them in a descending order.

Comment: @eminem So the rearranged result is still a valid SVD? In other words, can i simply use a sort algorithm to do the rearrangement?

Comment: In the _definition_ of the SVD, the values of $\Sigma$ are of descending order. You _can't_ put them however you like. You need to find them and arrange them at the right order.

Comment: Basically by applying a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) to $\Sigma$ and other matrices too. @niebayes, another answer: yes (recall the definition of SVD).

Comment: If you want to permute the singular values then you must also permute the singular vectors. Recall that the key equations for the SVD are $Av_i=\sigma_i u_i,A^T u_i=\sigma_i v_i$. Thus you must permute the columns of $U$ and the columns of $V$ (i.e. the *rows* of $V^T$) in the same manner that you permute the singular values. That being said, ordinarily the SVD is defined to already have the singular values sorted.

Comment: @Ian But if you use a permutation matrix it does not change the decomposition because basically it's like adding 1 and subtracting 1 to an equation.

Comment: @eminem Not sure what you mean by it not changing the decomposition. $(UP)(\Sigma P)(VP)^T$ is a different factorization. Relatedly, even with the monotonicity assumption on the singular values, and even with an additional *distinctness* assumption on the singular values, the SVD is far from unique.

Comment: YEs, you can, but then rows and columns in U and V are permuted. See notes in this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3752311/121671) for example

Answer (score 3):

There are several explanations of SVD all over the place. Here is a [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411486/understanding-singular-value-decomposition) to some explanation in this forum.

Here is a construction that gets the ordering as you asked.

Suppose $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix on $\mathbb{C}$. We use $A^*$ to denote the conjugate transpose of $A$ (this is an $n\times m$ matrix). In terms in operators on $L(\mathbb{C}^m,\mathbb{C}^n)$, $A^*$ is the operator that satisfies $$y^*Ax=\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,A^*y\rangle=(A^*y)^*x$$

- $A^*A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and satisfies $x^*A^*Ax=\langle Ax,Ax\rangle=\|Ax\|^2_2\geq0$.
- By known facts of linear algebra, $A^*A$ has $n$-eigenvalues, all real and non negative which then can be ordered decreasingly as $\sigma^2_1\geq \sigma^2_2\geq\ldots\geq\sigma^2_n$. Eigen vectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal, and so, we can find an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$ consistent of Eigen vectors .
- Suppose $r=\operatorname{rank}(A^*A)$. Then $r\leq (m,n)$, and so $\sigma^2_1\geq\ldots\geq\sigma^2_r>0=\sigma^2_{r+1}=\ldots\sigma^2_n$.
- We choose eigen vectors $u_j$ such that $$A^*Au_j=\sigma^2_j u_j,\quad 1\leq j\leq n$$ and $\langle u_i,u_j\rangle=u^*_ju_i=\delta_{ij}$. That is $\{u_j:1\leq j\leq n\}$ for an orthonormal basis of eigen vectors.
- In particular $$ \|Au_j\|^2=\langle Au_j,Au_j\rangle =\langle u_j,A^*Au_j\rangle =\sigma^2_j\langle u_j,u_j\rangle =\sigma^2_j$$ and so, $Au_j\neq 0$ for $1\leq j\leq r$ and $0$ otherwise.
- Define $Q$ as the $n\times n$ matrix whose $j$-th row is $u^*_j$. Clearly $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix since $QQ^*=I_n$ which in turn means that $Q^*Q=I_n$.
- For $i=1,\ldots ,r$ define $$v_i=\frac{1}{\sigma_i}Au_j$$
- Notice that if $1\leq i,j\leq r$, $$\langle v_i,v_j\rangle =\frac{1}{\sigma_i\sigma_j}\langle Au_i,Au_j\rangle=\frac{1}{\sigma_i\sigma_j}\langle u_i,A^*Au_j\rangle =\frac{\sigma_j}{\sigma_i}\delta_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$$
  That is, $\{v_j:1\leq j\leq r\}$ are orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{C}^m$.
- Complete $\{v_1,\ldots,v_r\}$ with vectors $\{v_{r+1},\ldots,v_m\}$ (if needed) to form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^m$. Define $P$ as the $m\times m$ matrix whose $i$-th column is $v_i$. Clearly, $P$ is an orthogonal matrix for $P^*P=I_m$ and so $PP^*=I_m$
- Notice that $D:=P^*AQ^*$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with main diagonal $(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_r,0,\ldots,0)$ and zeros everywhere else, for
  $$(P^*AQ^*)_{ij}=v^*_iAu_j=\sigma_jv_iv_j=\sigma_j\delta_{ij}$$
  for $1\leq j\leq r$, and $$(P^*AQ)_{ij}=v^*_iAu_j=\sigma_j v^*_iv_j=0=\sigma_j\delta_{ij}$$
  for $j>r$.
- Putting things together, one obtains $A=PDQ$, with the desired deceasing ordering in the main diagonal of $D$.

---

Some final remarks:

1. Matrices  $Q$ and $P$ in the SVD decomposition of $A$, even when the main diagonal of $D$ is ordered decreasingly, are not unique (there is a choice in ordering eigenvectors corresponding to an eigenvalue of multiplicity > 1, another choice for completing an orthonormal basis to construct $P$, and multiplication of vectors by unitary scales will produce also different $Q$s and $P$s)
2. If a particular SVD decomposition $P,D,Q$ of $A$ is given, **permutations** on the main diagonal of $D$ ($\sigma_j$ and $\sigma_i$ are interchanged), results in interchanging the $i$-th and $j$-th rows of $Q$ and the $i$-th and $j$-th columns of $P$ in order to keep an identity of the form $A=(P')D'(Q')^*$.
3. There are efficient numerical algorithms  to find the SVD decomposition already implemented in many libraries (BLAS, LAPACK, etc) that can be ported to Fortran, C, C++, etc. All of them, to my knowledge, produce an $m\times n$  diagonal $D$ matrix where the main diagonal is ordered decreasingly.

***Edit:***
To address the comment if @Ian, define $P^{>}$ as the $m\times r$ matrix whose $j$-th column is $v_j=Au_j$ ($1\leq j\leq r$) and $P^0$ the $m\times (m-r)$ matrix whose $j$-th columns are given by the $m-r$ vectors $v_j$ used to complete a basis for $\mathbb{C}^m$. Then $P=[P^>|P^0]$. Let $D_{>}$ be the $r\times r$  diagonal matrix $\operatorname(diag)(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_r)$.  Let $Q^>$ be the $r\times n$ matrix whose $i$-th row ($1\leq i\leq r$) is $u^*_i$, and $Q^0$ the $(n-r)\times n$ matrix whose $i$-th row is $u_i$, $r< I$, corresponding to the zero eigenvalues of $A^*A$, that is $Q=\begin{pmatrix} Q^>\\-\\Q^0\end{pmatrix}$. Then
\begin{align}
A&=PDQ=\begin{pmatrix}P^>|P^0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}D^>&|&0_{r\times(n-r)}\\
-&|&-\\
0_{(m-r)\times r} &| &0_{(m-r)\times(n-r)}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} Q^>\\-\\Q^0\end{pmatrix}\\
&=P^>D^>Q^>
\end{align}
Typical implementations of the svn algorithm has outputs $U=P^>_{m\times r}$, $\Sigma=D^>_{r\times r}$ and $V=Q^>_{r\times n}$.

Comment: Regarding your very last remark, there are algorithms you can ask to return $U$ as $m \times r$, $\Sigma$ as $r \times r$, and $V$ as $n \times r$ where $r$ is the numerical rank of $A$ (which is ordinarily computed by attempting to find the singular values anyway, so it is not an input into such algorithms). But certainly if you want $U$ and $V$ to be bona fide orthogonal matrices rather than just having orthonormal columns without necessarily being square, then $\Sigma$ will be $m \times n$.

Comment: @Ian: four years late but I Jost made an edit to address to comment.