# How was the singular value decomposition originally derived? How might one discover this decomposition from first principles?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

How was the singular value decomposition (SVD) method originally derived? How might one discover decomposition this from first principles?

---

Related Q&As that lend intuition to SVD but not derive or show how one might come up with such a decomposition:

1. [Understanding the singular value decomposition (SVD)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411486/understanding-the-singular-value-decomposition-svd)
2. [What is the intuition behind SVD? (cross validated stack exchange)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177102/what-is-the-intuition-behind-svd)

Comment: [Early history of the SVD](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/courses/229A/stewart-svd.pdf).